# How do i halt execution of bash script when a python script fails?

Tags: python, bash, error-handling, sh

So I have the following in my shell script:

```
python get_link.py $password | wget --content-disposition -i-
mkdir web_folder
mv *.zip web_folder
```

So the first line is **executing a python script** i wrote which **prints out a website link** and **wget immediately retrieves the link returned by the python script and downloads a zip file.**

The second line **makes a new folder** called "web_folder" and the **third line is moving the zip file** that was downloaded by wget into the "web_folder"

The problem I'm facing is that, if the python script fails due to error such as $password is having the wrong password, the rest of the shell script command is still executing. In my case, the following is printed:

```
mv: cannot stat ‘*.zip’: No such file or directory
```

The mkdir and the mv command somewhat still executes even if the python script fails. How do i ensure that the script comes to a complete halt when the python script fails?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using bash, look into PIPESTATUS variable.
${PIPESTATUS[0]} will have the return code from the first pipe.

```
#!/bin/bash
python get_link.py $password | wget --content-disposition -i-
if  [ ${PIPESTATUS[0]} -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "python get_link.py successful code here"
else
    echo "python get_link.py failed code here"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

A compact solution, chain everything with and's:

```
(python get_link.py $password | wget --content-disposition -i-) && (mkdir web_folder) && (mv *.zip web_folder)
```

Less compact solution:

```
python get_link.py $password | wget --content-disposition -i-
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  mkdir web_folder
  mv *.zip web_folder
fi
```